# Setting the date to the current date using datepicker in Spock/Geb

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, datepicker, spock, geb

I have the following code:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker span8" name="targetDeliveryDate" id="targetDeliveryDate" field="targetDeliveryDate" 
data-date-picker="true" data-date-future="true" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-date-autoclose="true" value="dd-MM-yyyy">
```

I have been setting the date using the code below:

```
$("#targetDeliveryDate").value  "01-12-2013"
```

Note that this is really static. However this is what the requirement was. But I'm expanding my tests and I need to set the date to the current active date.

I have looked at several posts but nothing works. I have tried the following but none of them work:

```
$("#targetDeliveryDate").val(new date());
$("#date_targetDeliveryDate").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Please let me know if there is a way we can set the date to current date.

Comment: do you want the input field to show current date on page load?

Comment: Yes please. I just want to populate the field with the current date

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = new Date();
var currDate

if (d.getDate() > 9) currDate = d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear()

else currDate = "0" + d.getDate() + "/" + (d.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + d.getFullYear()

$('#targetDeliveryDate').val(currDate)

$("#targetDeliveryDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5dAj/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By the way I'm using Groovy (and JDK) and if I use the above code, it says it's been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the date in the format you need:

```
var date = new Date();
var day = (date.getDay() < 10) ? "0" + date.getDay() : date.getDay();
var date_string = day + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getFullYear();
```

This should give you a in this format: "01-01-2013" (but with current date, so actually "02-12-2013")

Now you just need to set the value:

```
$("#targetDeliveryDate").val(date_string);
```

Comment: Hello there, I'm getting error messages stating that "getDay" and "getMonth" have been deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Having spent the whole evening trying to figure out the implementation, I have finally managed to resolve it and the code snippet is below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()                   
def currentDate     

if(cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH) > 9){
currentDate = (cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "-" + (cal.get(cal.MONTH) + 1) + "-" +   cal.getWeekYear();
}else{
currentDate = "0" + cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + (cal.get(cal.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + cal.getWeekYear();
}
```

And to set the value:

```
$(#targetDeliveryDate").value   currentDate
```

Thanks for the replies above.